# how to get this image and display it in angular 4 using http?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-http, angular4-forms

This is my java spring boot code. below code is the rest function to get image. using http get method how to call this method and display the image on angular 4 ?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/get-file",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getImage(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        Long a = new Long(6);
        ImageModel imageModel= imageRepository.getOne(a) ;

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageModel.getPic()); 
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
        //System.out.println("get image ");
    }
```

this is my angular code

```
public getCountry()
  {
    console.log("hey");
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/get-file';
   return this._http.get(url,{ responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map((res)=>res.blob());
  }
```

Comment: What did you try in Angular so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the service from Angular using HTTPCLIENT (if angular v4+), if CORS issue use proxy-config.json file, or enable cors.
2. Retrieve response from calling service in angular
3. Display image on angular via response

** might be better using CDN + sending URL from backend to frontend -- my 2cents